# Does ArcGIS tracking server 10.0 supports rest url?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, tracking-server

I'm using ArcGIS Tracking server 10.0 .

I know  Tracking server 10.1 has web connector but 10.0 version does not.

Does ArcGIS tracking server 10.0 supports rest url ?

Is it possible to use tracking services 10.0 version in the web or mobile device using rest or json ?

How can i do it ?